# What the heck did I do to this responsive navigation, and how can I fix it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I am trying to add responsive navigation to this page. In the desktop version it should be a nav bar that runs 600px, and is on the right side of the banner area in a single line. In tablet view, it should split to two stacked rows beneath the logo (which moves to the center). In phone view, I need it to have a full-width "menu" bar that, when clicked, drops down all the other menu items. Can't get it to do that for the life of me, though. The desktop version works ok, but the others don't.  I've been working on this for a couple days and am really frustrated. Help please?

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */



/* typography */
body{
 color:#666;
 font-family:'Ubuntu', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 font-size:1em;
 line-height:1.4em; 
 font-weight:normal;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
 font-weight:normal;
 font-family:'Droid Serif', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 line-height:1.5em;
 margin:.45em 0;
 padding:0;
} 
/* Box sizing. */
*{ -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;}

/* links */
a,
a:visited,
a:active,
a:hover{color:#0099ff;}
a:hover{ text-decoration:none;}

#logo {
 float: left
}  


/*MOBILE PHONE*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
  nav {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
  }
  nav a#pull {
    display: block;
    background-color: #283744;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav a#pull:after {
    content:"";
    background: url('nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
  }
}
/* structure */   
.wrapper{
 width: 92%; 
 margin: 0 auto;
}
header{ 
 padding:15px 0;
}
#banner{ 
 text-align:center;
}
 
#hero,
#page-header{
 background:#f3f3f3;
 border-top:1px solid #e2e2e2;
 border-bottom:1px solid #e2e2e2;
 padding:20px 0;
}

#hero h1{ 
 line-height:1.2em;
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-bottom:10px;}

#content {  
 margin:40px 0;
}

p{ margin:0 0 1.5em;}



/* RESPONSIVE IMAGES */
img{ max-width:100%; height:auto;}


/*NAV BAR*/
/*will have 50% of area on top, will have right float*/
nav {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  background: #0099ff;
  font-size: 11pt;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #283744;
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 40px;
}

/*float menu links to the left*/
nav li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

/*Add clearfix hack style rules*/
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
/*Since there are 5 links each should be 120px*/
nav a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  }

/*separate each link by a 1px right border except for last one.*/
/*Change the box-sizing model to border-box to keep menu at 120px*/
nav li a {
  border-right: 1px solid #576979;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
nav li:last-child a {
  border-right: 0;
}

/*Add hover state to turn it to grey*/
nav a:hover, nav a:active {
  background-color: #8c99a4;
  color: #fff;
}

nav {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }


/*SPACE GRID ELEMENTS VERTICALLY, SINCE THEY ARE ONE UNDER ANOTHER IN MOBILE VIEW*/
.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9,
.grid_10,
.grid_11,
.grid_12 {
 margin-bottom:40px;
 /*positioning and padding*/
 position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
  
}

/*FOOTER*/
footer{  
 clear:both;
 font-size:80%;
 padding:20px 0;
 align-content: center;
}
footer ul{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 align-content: center;
}

/*colors and backgrounds*/
body{
 background:#fff;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
 color:#333; 
}

footer{ 
 background:#333;
 color:#ccc;
 align-content: center;
}
footer h1, footer h2, footer h3, footer h4{ 
 color:#CCC; 
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
footer ul{
 margin:0 0 0 8%;
 align-content: center;
}

a.buttonlink{ 
 background:#0099ff; 
 border-radius:7px; 
 color:#fff;
 display:block;
 float:left; 
 margin:10px 15px 10px 0; 
 padding:10px;
 text-decoration:none;
}
a.buttonlink:hover{
 background:#CCCCCC;
}



/* Contain floats*/ 
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,
.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after,
.container:after,
.row:after{
  clear: both;
}



/* TABLET & SMALLER LAPTOPS */
/*navigation*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1050px;
  margin: .75em auto;
 }
#banner{ 
 float:left; 
 text-align:left;
 margin-bottom:0px;
}

header{
 padding:0;
}
#content {  
 float:left;
 width:65%;
}
#content.wide-content{
 float:none;
 width:100%;
}


.clearfix:after,
.container:after,
.row:after{
  clear: both;
}
}

 
/* DESKTOP*/
/*navigation*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
nav {
  height: 40px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #0099ff;
  position: relative;
  
}
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 40px;
}
 nav a#pull {
  display: none;
} 

/*GRID*/
/*
 & Columns : 12 

 */
 .row{
  margin-left: -15px;
     margin-right: -15px;
}
 
.grid_1 { width: 8.33333333%; }
.grid_2 { width: 16.66666667%; }
.grid_3 { width: 25%; }
.grid_4 { width: 33.33333333%; }
.grid_5 { width: 41.66666667%; }
.grid_6 { width: 50%; }
.grid_7 { width: 58.33333333%; }
.grid_8 { width: 66.66666667%; }
.grid_9 { width: 75%; }
.grid_10 { width: 83.33333333%; }
.grid_11 { width: 91.66666667%; }
.grid_12 { width: 100%; }

.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9,
.grid_10,
.grid_11,
.grid_12 {
 float: left;
 display: block;
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

<title>GREKOS' GREEK RESTAURANT</title>
<meta name="description" content="Grekos' Restaurant is a family-owned restaurant in Regina, Saskatchewan serving authentic Greek food.">
<meta name="keywords" content="Greek restaurant Regina, Greek food Regina, Regina restaurants, Baklava, Moussaka, Regina Saskatchewan">

<!-- Mobile viewport -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">


<!-- CSS-->
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/grekostyle.css">
<!-- end CSS-->


</head>

<body id="home">

    <header class="wrapper clearfix">         
        <div id="banner">        
         <div id="logo"><a href="#"><img src="images/grekoslogo.png" alt="Grekos Logo" width="140"/></a></div> 
        </div>
        
 <nav class="clearfix">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menus</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reservations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>    
  </ul>
  <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
</nav>
        
  
    </header>
 
 

    <section id="hero" class="clearfix">    
  
    <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="row"> 
        <div class="grid_5">
            <h1>Grekos' Greek Restaurant</h1>
            <h3><i>Come Taste The Difference!</i></h3>
            <p>Since 1979, Grekos' Greek Restaurant has been serving hungry Regina patrons with tasty, authentic Greek food. The dream of George, Bob and Chris, three brothers from the Peloponnese region of southern Greece, Grekos has earned the reputation of being one of Regina's outstanding restaurants - and more. It has become a gathering place for groups, business meetings, and family memories.</p>

   <p><i>"The real test for any restaurant is that people want to come back,"</i> says George. <i>"That is what we strive to achieve every day."</i></p>

    <p>From the moment you step through the front doors, you enter a whole new world, with a cosy, relaxing ambiance, tantalizing food and always, a warm welcome. </p>
   <p><a href="#" class="buttonlink">SPECIAL EVENTS</a></p> 
         <p><a href="#" class="buttonlink">CALL FOR RESERVATIONS</a></p>
          </div> 
        <div class="grid_7 leftfloat">
                         <img src="images/interior.jpg" alt="Grekos interior picture" />
                          <p class="flex-caption">Grekos' Greek Restaurant offers a pleasing, relaxing atmosphere.</p>
                   
                        
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </section>





<!-- main content area -->   
<body>
 <div id="main" class="wrapper">
    
    
<!-- content area -->    
 <section id="content" class="wide-content">
      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="grid_4">
          <h1 class="first-header">Lunch Menu</h1>
            <img src="images/greeksalad.jpg" alt="Lunch Menu, Greek Salad photo
" width="400" />
            <p>Quick service, a welcoming atmosphere and authentic Greek cuisine make Grekos' your <i>"go to"</i> lunch destination.<br>
<a href="#" class="buttonlink">Lunch Menu</a></p><br>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid_4">
 
          <h1 class="first-header">Dinner Menu</h1>
            <img src="images/souvlaki.jpg" width="400" />
            <p>Treat yourself and your family to traditional Hellenic (Greek) meals - we guarantee a memorable dining experience at affordable prices.<br>
            <a href="#" class="buttonlink">Dinner Menu</a></p><br><br>
            
        </div>
     
        <div class="grid_4">
         <h1 class="first-header">Drinks, Coffees & Desserts</h1>
            <img src="images/drinks.jpg" width="400" />

            <p>Enjoy one of our refreshing beverages, and top your meal off with our delectable desserts... and of course, don't forget your Greek coffee afterward!<br><a href="#" class="buttonlink">Drinks, Coffees & Desserts Menu</a></p> <br><br>
        </div>
   </div>
 </section>      
         
  </div>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>$(function() {
  var pull    = $('#pull');
    menu    = $('nav ul');
    menuHeight  = menu.height();
 
  $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle();
  });
});
 $(window).resize(function(){
  var w = $(window).width();
  if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
    menu.removeAttr('style');
  }
}); 
 </script>
 </body>

<!-- footer area -->    
<footer>
 <div class="wrapper clearfix">
     <b>Grekos' Greek Restaurant </b> 4410 Albert Street, Regina  |  306.584.3646
    </div>
   
</footer><!-- #end footer area --> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your CSS code should be re-organized with the smallest viewport styles NOT in a media query. This way your default styles are for mobile devices (which constitute the majority of web users these days), then following that, you should set up media queries for progressively larger viewports and only write styles for the things that need to change.

Comment: Thanks, @ScottMarcus. So - take the media queries for mobile (which are at the bottom) and just put the code, minus the media queries, on top, followed by progressively larger?

Comment: @ScottMarcus - I tried to do that just now but it broke the desktop view menu then.

Comment: @DMB66 That is because you have to take all the styles from mobile view  out when doing the desktop view.
The way I usually styles menu is by doing the following:
1) Global menu styles
   - Colors, background colors, hover effects...
2) `@media (max-width: mobile-view)` - Change that to whatever size you like
   - Do everything you need for mobile
3)  `@media (min-width: tablet-view)`
   - Do everything for tablet view
4) `@media (min-width: desktop-view)`
   - Do everything for desktop view

If desktop and tablet are going to be similar you can just do `@media (min-width: #px)

Comment: Hi, you have <body> twice in the html. Your first <body id="home"> is good. At the bottom you have the and </body> twice. Take out the one under  </script>↩ </body>↩ My wife's family is from Evia, right below Kymi. :D

Comment: I'm so sorry everyone - I just can't figure out all the lines of code and what goes where. Thanks for your help anyway. I am just so confused.